# Git diff, file can't be found?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4

Maybe I'm getting the file format wrong, but I'm not sure why this is not working...

git diff CSS:_requestpage.html.erb MoveSuccessModal:_requestpage.html.erb
   fatal: Path '_requestpage.html.erb' does not exist in 'CSS'

And that file is in

```
APPNAME > app > views > layouts > _requestpage.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to execute git diff with the full path.

in your case:
**`git diff APPNAME/app/views/layouts/_requestpage.html.erb`**

**[Here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/git-diff/)** is a very detailed post about diff.

Comment: I tried that, I got `fatal: ambiguous argument 'lastmingear/app/config/database.yml': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: Did you add the remote correctly? view your .git/config file to find out